# Regex function to extract data in sub groups

Tags: regex, vb.net

I am trying to extract the below data into Main group and sub groups in vb.net

> (abc())(def((123)(456))(klm((123))

Result Expected 
Match 1 : abc 
Match 2 : def 
*Group 1 : 123* 
*Group 2 : 456* 
Match 3 : klm 
*Group 1 : 123*

I  have tried the below code `(\w+)\((\d+)\)`, but its not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want to match a "word" followed with parenthesized numbers inside parentheses. A generic approach here would cater for scenarios with unknown amount of `(num)`s inside the parentheses after the word.

You can use

```
(\w+)\((?:\((\d+)\))*\)
```

and rely on the [*Match.Captures*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.group.captures?view=net-8.0) property that is accessible in the .NET regex API. Here is a way to access all the group and capture values:

```vb
Imports System
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public Class Test
    Public Shared Sub Main() 
        Dim pattern As String = "(\w+)\((?:\((\d+)\))*\)"
        Dim text As String = "(abc())(def((123)(456))(klm((123))"
        Dim matches As MatchCollection = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(text, pattern)
        For Each m As Match In matches
            Console.WriteLine("Match: " & m.Groups(1).Value)
            For Each g As Capture in m.Groups(2).Captures
                Console.WriteLine("Capture: " & g.Value)
            Next
        Next
        
    End Sub
End Class
```

See [this VB.NET demo](https://ideone.com/tQq2CO) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/E934lT/1). Output:

```
Match: abc
Match: def
Capture: 123
Capture: 456
Match: klm
Capture: 123
```

The `(\w+)\((?:\((\d+)\))*\)` regex matches

- `(\w+)` - Group 1: one or more word chars
- `\(` - a `(` char
- `(?:\((\d+)\))*` - zero or more repetitions of

  - `\(` - a `(` char
  - `(\d+)` - Group 2: one or more digits
  - `\)` - a `)` char
- `\)` - a `)` char

Answer (score 2):

You could use this regex, which matches letters preceded by a `(`, then uses a forward lookahead to capture either one or two sets of digits inside `()`:

```
(?<=\()[a-z]+(?=\((?:\((\d+)\))?(?:\((\d+)\))?\))
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/TS9Fag/1)

Sample VB.Net code:

```vb
Imports System
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public Class Test
    Public Shared Sub Main() 
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim pattern As String = "(?<=\()[a-z]+(?=\((?:\((\d+)\))?(?:\((\d+)\))?\))"
        Dim text As String = "(abc())(def((123)(456))(klm((123))"
        Dim matches As MatchCollection = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(text, pattern)
        For Each m As Match In matches
            i = 0
            For Each g As Group in m.Groups
                If i = 0 Then
                    Console.WriteLine("Match: " & g.Value)
                ElseIf i > 0 and g.Value <> "" Then
                    Console.WriteLine("Group " & i & ": " & g.Value)
                End If
                i = i + 1
            Next
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Output:

```
Match: abc
Match: def
Group 1: 123
Group 2: 456
Match: klm
Group 1: 123
```

[Demo on ideone.com](https://ideone.com/RdLe0O)